How can I put images in the gallery in Flutter while the emulator is on?
See this picture
How can I put images in the gallery in Flutter while the emulator is on?
I already insert the function of the XFile and image picker but still no pictures showing up in the gallery. The camera is okay but the gallery doesn't. What should I do to have images in the gallery so that I can able to use it from Scanning the images. I tried everything, research in YT but still have no clue.

Please share any screenshots of errors or issues you're encountering for better understanding. Kindly follow all the steps mentioned in this package, and also make sure to test it on a real device for accurate results
image_picker

All what you have to do is to drag image and drop it inside my files or inside the gallery this worked fine with me
